# Modificar Input hidden creado con helper form cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp

cuando uso el helper Form de cakephp 3 para crear los formularios que es el siguiente:

```
<?= $this->Form->create() ?>
```

y el output es el siguinete:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" 
action="/serappdev/preguntasalternativas/edit/1/2">
<div style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
</div>
```

bueno ahora mi duda es como puedo modificar el value del input que se crea de manera predeterminada.

Comment: ¿Puedo preguntar sobre el motivo para querer hacer eso?

Comment: Bueno lo necesito para una validación de tipo put ya que cuando recupero la información lo hago a través de un select y no por el metodo get